# Split json sturc value into multiple columns in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am importing a json file into pyspark dataframe. I have import the json with following code

```
df = sqlContext.read.json("json_file.json").select("item", "attributes")
```

I want to split attributes from one column to multiple columns.

Here is sample json format:

```
{"item":"item-1","attributes":{"att-a":"att-a-15","att-b":"att-b-10","att-c":"att-c-7"}}
{"item":"item-2","attributes":{"att-a":"att-a-15","att-b":"att-b-10","att-c":"att-c-7"}}
```

Comment: share your expected output from this json file

Comment: Use `Select("attributes.*") `

Comment: can you please add you expected output

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see your output to be like this

```
+------+--------+--------+-------+
|  item|   att-a|   att-b|  att-c|
+------+--------+--------+-------+
|item-1|att-a-15|att-b-10|att-c-7|
|item-2|att-a-15|att-b-10|att-c-7|
+------+--------+--------+-------+
```

Use

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df.select('item','attributes.*').show()
```

So that all attributes you can see it in the multiple columns.